# Check if first and last character contains given special char

Tags: javascript, regex

I have input string

```
..-----''''''.......VAibhavs.sharma'..'-.'-.''-....''
```

I want to check if the first and last char place contains `-` or `'` or `.`.

If yes then `trim` until we get name.

Expected output : `VAibhavs.sharma`

I am using like this.

```js
while (
    myString.charAt(0) == "." ||
    myString.charAt(0) == "'" ||
    myString.charAt(0) == "-" ||
    myString.charAt(myString.length - 1) == "." ||
    myString.charAt(myString.length - 1) == "'" ||
    myString.charAt(myString.length - 1) == "-"
)
```

I know this is not correct way. How can I use regex?

I tried `/^\'$`. But this only checks or first char for a single special char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```js
input = "..-----''''''.......VAibhavs.sharma'..'-.'-.''-....''"
output = input.replace(/^[-'\.]+/,"").replace(/[-'\.]+$/,"")
console.log(output)
```

- `[-'\.]` ... `-`, `'` or `.` character
- `+` ... one or more times
- `^` ... beginning of the string
- `$` ... end of the string

EDIT:

using `match`:

```js
input = "..-----''''''.......VAibhavs.sharma'..'-.'-.''-....''"
output = input.match(/^[-'\.]+(.*?)[-'\.]+$/)[1]
console.log(output)
```

- `(...)` ... (1st) group
- `.*?` ... any chacter, zero or more times, `?` means non-greedy
- `.match(...)[1]` ... `1` means 1st group

Answer (score 0):

There is already one accepted answer but still, this is how I would do.

```
var pattern = /\b[A-Za-z.]+\b/gm;
var str = "..-----''''''.......VAibhavs.sharma'..'-.'-.''-....''";
console.log(str.match(pattern));

// Output
// ["VAibhavs.sharma"]
```

`\b` is a zero-width word boundary. It matches positions where one side is a word character (usually a letter, digit or underscore) and the other side is not a word character (for instance, it may be the beginning of the string or a space character).